# Accessing values in CLIPS?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips

Assume I have the following set of definstances which show the inputs and outputs of various stages of an electric circuit. I don't include all the classes and instances as I don't think it's relevant to my problem. I will include a photo that will help you understand how this problem works.

[image]

The code below is from Protege, the code of Ontology.
We have 10 cycles.

```
(defclass systemEntity
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot suspect
        (type SYMBOL)
        (allowed-values yes no)
        (default no)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete))

(defclass component
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role abstract))

(defclass sensor
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot theoretical
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot reading
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes internal-component)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass internal-component
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot short-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 0)
        (default 0)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot output
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot msb-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 15)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input2
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input1
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass adder
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass multiplier
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass circuit
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete)
    (multislot outputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot has-components
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot inputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
(create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass data
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot clock
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 1 ?VARIABLE)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot value
        (type INTEGER)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass reading_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write)))
        
(definstances facts 
    
    
    ([a1] of  adder
    
        (input1 [input_1])
        (input2 [input_1])
        (output
            [m1]
            [p1])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([a2] of  adder
    
        (input1 [p1])
        (input2 [p2])
        (output [out1])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([circuit_1] of  circuit
    
        (has-components
            [m1]
            [m2]
            [m3]
            [out1]
            [a1]
            [a2]
            [p1]
            [p2])
        (inputs
            [input_1]
            [input_2]
            [input_3]
            [input_4])
        (outputs [out1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([command_10_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 6))
    
    ([command_10_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 4))
    
    ([command_10_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_10_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 12))
    
    ([command_1_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 21))
    
    ([command_1_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 28))
    
    ([command_1_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 10))
    
    ([command_1_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_2_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 7))
    
    ([command_2_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_2_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 13))
    
    ([command_2_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 15))
    
    ([command_3_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_3_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 17))
    
    ([command_3_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 24))
    
    ([command_3_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_4_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([command_4_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_4_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 28))
    
    ([command_4_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 21))
    
    ([command_5_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_5_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([command_5_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 30))
    
    ([command_5_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 10))
    
    ([command_6_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([command_6_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 19))
    
    ([command_6_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_6_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 19))
    
    ([command_7_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 1))
    
    ([command_7_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_7_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 7))
    
    ([command_7_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 22))
    
    ([command_8_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([command_8_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_8_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 3))
    
    ([command_8_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 23))
    
    ([command_9_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_9_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 1))
    
    ([command_9_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 6))
    
    ([command_9_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 8))
    
    ([input_1] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_2] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_3] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_4] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m1] of  sensor
    
        (input [a1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m2] of  sensor
    
        (input [p1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m3] of  sensor
    
        (input [p2])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([out1] of  sensor
    
        (input [a2])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([p1] of  multiplier
    
        (input1 [input_2])
        (input2 [a1])
        (output
            [m2]
            [a2])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([p2] of  multiplier
    
        (input1 [input_3])
        (input2 [input_4])
        (output
            [m3]
            [a2])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([reading_10_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_10_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([reading_10_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_10_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [out1])
        (value 28))
    
    ([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m1])
        (value 10))
    
    ([reading_1_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([reading_1_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m3])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_1_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [out1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([reading_2_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_2_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_2_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m3])
        (value 3))
    
    ([reading_2_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [out1])
        (value 3))
    
    ([reading_3_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m1])
        (value 22))
    
    ([reading_3_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m2])
        (value 6))
    
    ([reading_3_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m3])
        (value 8))
    
    ([reading_3_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [out1])
        (value 14))
    
    ([reading_4_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m1])
        (value 4))
    
    ([reading_4_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m2])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_4_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_4_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [out1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_5_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([reading_5_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m2])
        (value 16))
    
    ([reading_5_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_5_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [out1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_6_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m1])
        (value 8))
    
    ([reading_6_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([reading_6_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m3])
        (value 17))
    
    ([reading_6_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [out1])
        (value 9))
    
    ([reading_7_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m1])
        (value 2))
    
    ([reading_7_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_7_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m3])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_7_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [out1])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_8_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m3])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [out1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_9_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m1])
        (value 30))
    
    ([reading_9_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m2])
        (value 30))
    
    ([reading_9_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m3])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_9_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [out1])
        (value 30))


)
```

By using the following code i can calculate the A1.

```
(defrule check_a1
    (fact ?clock ?object ?value)
    (test (eq ?object [input_1]))
    =>
    (assert (fact ?clock [m1t] (mod(+ ?value ?value)(** 2 5)))))
```

How can i calculate the Π1?

Answer (score 0):

If you look through your code, you can see the information for adder and multiplier referenced in your question.

```
([a1] of  adder
    (input1 [input_1])
    (input2 [input_1])
    (output
        [m1]
        [p1])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))

([p1] of  multiplier
    (input1 [input_2])
    (input2 [a1])
    (output
        [m2]
        [a2])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))
```

It's not clear how your check_a1 rule can correctly calculate anything. It matches facts, but the protege code contains only instances. It's also not clear looking at the protege code where the input/output values for the internal-components are stored.

If you write rules specific rules for each component, you have to change those rules if you run your program with a different circuit. It's better to write generic rules for each component type. For example:

```
(defrule adder
   (object (is-a multiplier)
           (name ?name)
           (input1 ?input1)
           (input2 ?input2)
           )
   ;; Pattern to retrieve input1 value
   ;; Pattern to retrieve input2 value
   =>
   ;; Compute output value
   )
```

One additional issue that you will see with the protege code is that a concrete class inheriting from an abstract class will not match rules unless you declare the pattern-match attribute to be reactive: (pattern-match reactive)